# Maven2:List return type methods not getting generated from .xsd files while using xmlbeans plugin

Tags: maven, ant, xmlbeans, xmlbeans-maven-plugin

I am tring to build my project using maven2.This project was succesfully build using ANT in netbeans IDE.
Now the problem is, I am able to generate the .java files from .xsd files using xmlbeans maven plugin.But some getter setter methods having java.util.list as return type is not getting generated.

Please help me..I am not able to do my build beacuse of this :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `javasource` version to 1.5 to get List support in XmlBeans.

Comment: Actually i am doing development on MAC OS X lion where its java 1.6.So what can i do here?.

Comment: Actually i am doing development on MAC OS X lion where its java 1.6.So what can i do here?.Can i use any other plugins which do not have any dependencies like this.
Installing 1.5 in mac OS x Lion dont know will it work!! :(

Comment: Thanks artbristol :) :)..its working.... 

i got my war file created with maven... but when i deploy it in tomcat its throwing 404 error when trying to access it?..but the ant built war file runs perfect?...where can i go wrong??

Comment: Best to accept this answer, then post a new question with your current problem.