# xmlbeans-maven-plugin not generating getters for Lists

Tags: maven, xmlbeans-maven-plugin

I'm currently trying to build a legacy project which has been migrated from Ant to Maven. This project uses the `xmlbeans-maven-plugin` to build java classes from `.xsd` source files. Everything works fine until a `get...List()` method gets called. All List-getters seem to be missing. All the information I could find points to a Java version being used that does not support Lists. The solution that worked for most people was changing the `javaSource` tag in the plugin configuration to `1.5`. This did not solve my problem.

The relevant part of my `pom.xml` currently looks like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <javaSource>1.8</javaSource>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Another stackoverflow thread ([Maven2:List return type methods not getting generated from .xsd files while using xmlbeans plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631439/maven2list-return-type-methods-not-getting-generated-from-xsd-files-while-usin)), from 2011 mind you, suggests to set the Java version to 1.5 instead. This gives me another error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:xmlbeans-maven-plugin:2.3.3:xmlbeans (default) on project ...: XmlBeans compile failed:
 xml ErrorLoading schema file ...
 xml ErrorLoading schema file ...
 xml ErrorLoading schema file ...
 xml ErrorLoading schema file ...
 xml ErrorLoading schema file ...
```

The solution for this problem I found [here](https://github.com/ethercis/openehr-java-libs/issues/1) tells me this is a problem with Java 11 and that I should set the Java version to 1.8.

Here's a snippet of one of the `.xsd` files:

```
<xs:element name="DbcFile" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="path" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This should generate a method called `getDbcFileList()`. However, as you can see from this error message, it does not do that:

```
... cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getDbcFileList()
```

It does generate `getDbcFileArray()`. I have tried a lot of combinations of changing Java versions, removing the build folder every time to get a clean build, you name it. I'm honestly out of ideas.

I'm using Maven 3.6.3 and OpenJDK 13.0.2+8_2. I'm running maven commands from IntelliJ 2020.1. The only thing I haven't tried is downgrading my JDK, but I feel like that won't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The solution was to downgrade to JDK 1.8, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when upgrading from JDK 1.8 to JDK 11. The xmlbeans-maven-plugin is old but if you have to stick with it then the solution is to add following attributes to `<configuration>` section for the plugin in `pom.xml`:

```
<noJavac>true</noJavac>
<javaSource>1.6</javaSource>
```

The author was close to solution but `<javaSource>` attribute alone is not enough. Setting `<noJavac>` prevents xmlbeans from calling compilation with argument "-source" pointing to possibly no longer supported Java versions, in my case 1.4.

I see the OP linked the thread where I found solution, but back then the part about javac was missing: https://github.com/ethercis/openehr-java-libs/issues/1#issuecomment-880253566.